# Not compiling assets when using webpack-dev-server

Tags: webpack, assets, webpack-dev-server

This is my project configuration:

```
"webpack": "^4.16.5",
"webpack-cli": "^3.1.0",
"webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.5"
```

When I run `npx webpack --config webpack.config.js` everything is running as expected - all of the assets are compiled and `assets` folder is created.

When I run `webpack-dev-server` command only a server is started, the assets are compiled, but the `assets` folder is not created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The assets folder is not created because `webpack-dev-server` or `webpack-dev-middleware` creates all your bundler in memory. This means that the browser is going to access the content served from the memory by `webpack-dev-server`.

When you directly run `webpack`, that creates actual files. Nothing is wrong here.